# Error in [: invalid subscript type 'list' in R Shiny

Tags: r, database, shiny, internationalization

I'm working on building a Shiny app that filters data by different parameters. I have two versions of this data, one in English and one in French. Each dataset has 1879 observations by 9 variables (one of these variables is the language identifier, which is hidden when the app runs). Currently, I am able to toggle between the data and choose filters. However, the issue arises when I have more than one filter selected and toggle the language. I receive an error reading "Error in [: invalid subscript type 'list'". I assume this has to do with the fact that the data is in two different languages. I have looked into the shiny.i18n package, however, I don't think that's the best route to go as I have the translation working fine other than this error. Here is my code below. It probably isn't the cleanest but any suggestions with that would also be appreciated.

```
# UI ----------------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- shinyUI(
  
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel(uiOutput("app_title")),
    selectInput("language", "Language", choices = c("EN", "FR"), selected = "EN"),
    selectInput("subject", "Subject", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(dat$subject, ", "))))), selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
    selectInput("census_year", "Census Year(s) covered by item", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(dat$yearItem, ", "))))), selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
    selectInput("geo_units", "Geographic units", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(dat$geoUnits, ", "))))), selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
    selectInput("geo_coverage", "Geographic coverage", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(dat$geoCov, ", "))))), selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
    selectInput("format", "Format", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(dat$format, ", "))))), selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
    DT::DTOutput('ex1')
    
  )
  
)


# SERVER ------------------------------------------------------------------

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  #App title changes with language
  app_title <- reactive({
    if (input$language == "EN") {
      return("app title")
    } else {
      return("titre de l'application")
    }
  })
  
  output$app_title <- renderUI({
    titlePanel(app_title())
  })
  
  #If the language is English, subset the data (removing the 9th row with the language identifier)
  observe({
    if (input$language == "EN") {
      filtered_dat <- subset(dat, language == "EN")[,-9] # Remove 9th column
      
      
      updateSelectInput(session, "subject", "Subject", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$subject, ", "))))), selected = input$subject)
      updateSelectInput(session, "census_year","Census Year(s) covered by item", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$yearItem, ", "))))), selected = input$census_year)
      updateSelectInput(session, "geo_units","Geographic units", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$geoUnits, ", "))))), selected = input$geo_units)
      updateSelectInput(session, "geo_coverage","Geographic coverage", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$geoCov, ", "))))), selected = input$geo_coverage)
      updateSelectInput(session, "format","Format", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$format, ", "))))), selected = input$format)
    } else {
  #If the language is French, subset the data (removing the 9th row with the language identifier)
      filtered_dat <- subset(dat, language == "FR")[,-9] # Remove 9th column
      
      updateSelectInput(session, "subject", "Sujet", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$subject, ", "))))), selected = input$subject)
      updateSelectInput(session, "census_year","Année(s) de recensement couverte(s) par l’item", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$yearItem, ", "))))), selected = input$census_year)
      updateSelectInput(session, "geo_units","Unités géographiques", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$geoUnits, ", "))))), selected = input$geo_units)
      updateSelectInput(session, "geo_coverage","Couverture géographique", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$geoCov, ", "))))), selected = input$geo_coverage)
      updateSelectInput(session, "format","Format", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$format, ", "))))), selected = input$format)
    }
    #Allow for the user to select the filters in any order with no auto-population 
    
    if(!is.null(input$subject)) {
      filtered_dat <- filtered_dat[sapply(strsplit(filtered_dat$subject, ", "), function(x) any(input$subject %in% x)),]
      updateSelectInput(session, "census_year", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$yearItem, ", "))))), selected = input$census_year)
      updateSelectInput(session, "geo_units", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$geoUnits, ", "))))), selected = input$geo_units)
      updateSelectInput(session, "geo_coverage", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$geoCov, ", "))))), selected = input$geo_coverage)
      updateSelectInput(session, "format", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$format, ", "))))), selected = input$format)
    }
    
    if(!is.null(input$census_year)) {
      filtered_dat <- filtered_dat[sapply(strsplit(filtered_dat$yearItem, ", "), function(x) any(input$census_year %in% x)),]
      updateSelectInput(session, "subject", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$subject, ", "))))), selected = input$subject)
      updateSelectInput(session, "geo_units", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$geoUnits, ", "))))), selected = input$geo_units)
      updateSelectInput(session, "geo_coverage", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$geoCov, ", "))))), selected = input$geo_coverage)
      updateSelectInput(session, "format", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$format, ", "))))), selected = input$format)
    }
    
    if(!is.null(input$geo_units)){
      filtered_dat <- filtered_dat[sapply(strsplit(filtered_dat$geoUnits, ", "), function(x) any(input$geo_units %in% x)),]
      updateSelectInput(session, "subject", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$subject, ", "))))), selected = input$subject)
      updateSelectInput(session, "census_year", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$yearItem, ", "))))), selected = input$census_year)
      updateSelectInput(session, "geo_coverage", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$geoCov, ", "))))), selected = input$geo_coverage)
      updateSelectInput(session, "format", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$format, ", "))))), selected = input$format)
    }
    
    if(!is.null(input$geo_coverage)){
      filtered_dat<-filtered_dat[sapply(strsplit(filtered_dat$geoCov, ", "), function(x) any(input$geo_coverage %in% x)), ]
      updateSelectInput(session, "subject", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$subject, ", "))))), selected = input$subject)
      updateSelectInput(session, "census_year", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$yearItem, ", "))))), selected = input$census_year)
      updateSelectInput(session, "geo_units", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$geoUnits, ", "))))), selected = input$geo_units)
      updateSelectInput(session, "format", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$format, ", "))))), selected = input$format)
    }
    
    if(!is.null(input$format)){
      filtered_dat<-filtered_dat[sapply(strsplit(filtered_dat$format, ", "), function(x) any(input$format %in% x)), ]
      updateSelectInput(session, "subject", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$subject, ", "))))), selected = input$subject)
      updateSelectInput(session, "census_year", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$yearItem, ", "))))), selected = input$census_year)
      updateSelectInput(session, "geo_units", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$geoUnits, ", "))))), selected = input$geo_units)
      updateSelectInput(session, "geo_coverage", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$geoCov, ", "))))), selected = input$geo_coverage)
    }
    #in the output of the table, change the DISPLAYED column names dependent on the language selected
    output$ex1 <- DT::renderDT({
      lang <- input$language
      if (lang == "EN") {
        colnames <- c("Title", "Link", "Census year (of publication)",
                      "Census Year(s) covered by item", "Subject", 
                      "Geographic coverage", "Geographic units","Format")
      } else {
        colnames <- c("Titre", "Link", "Année de recensement (de la publication)",
                      "Année(s) de recensement couverte(s) par l’item", "Sujet", 
                      "Couverture géographique", "Unités géographiques","Format")
      }
      DT::datatable(filtered_dat, 
                    colnames = colnames,
                    escape = FALSE)
    })
    
    
  })
  
})  

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You would likely get more traffic and bites if you provided sufficient data from `dat` to try this code.

Comment: I, unfortunately, cannot provide the data due to sensitive information.

Comment: Yes, I understand, proprietary data is always a hard thing. But realize that (1) it doesn't need to be _real_ data, just _representative_ data; and (2) I (among others, perhaps) am not going to spend time to infer what might be data in order to try to play with your code.